Do not display brower in Notebook when running Gradio
When using .launch function of Gradio, it will attempt to render the webpage in Jupyter cell. How can I set this to not display? Shown in the grey area.
Does is have to do with notebook config? I don't think its c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False.
